# SCDF on k8s: Producer exception when sending message to Kafka - ticktock + no messages on ticktock.time topic

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

The timer application throws a per-second error when trying to send its message to *Kafka*:

```
2017-08-03 10:20:58,805 ERROR kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2 o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener:76 - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{-1, 2, 11, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 0, 0, 0, 12, 34, 116, 101, 120, 116...' to topic metrics: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for metrics-0 due to 30009 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

It seems to me like these would be the records for the metrics topic, but at the same time there are no records in the ticktock.timer topic in *Kafka*.
I'm guessing this partition key being null could be the problem. But I am not so sure why it should use some partitioning setup that is not the default one.

Here's what I deployed:

```
dataflow:> app register --type sink --name log --uri docker://springcloudstream/log-sink-kafka-10:1.2.0.RELEASE --metadata-uri maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE dataflow:> app register --type source --name time --uri docker://springcloudstream/time-source-kafka-10:1.2.0.RELEASE --metadata-uri maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-kafka-10:jar:metadata:1.2.0.RELEASE dataflow:> stream create --name ticktock --definition "time | log" --deploy
```

And here's my setup:

```
spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes: 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Spring Cloud Data Flow Core: 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
Spring Cloud Dataflow UI: 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm using *Kafka 10* BTW.

What could be the problem?

Many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

It looks odd that the time source application's log has the producer publishing to the `metrics` topic. By any chance, you have this topic configured as part of this stream?

I assume the stream deployment has the topic `ticktock.time` created and can you share if there are any other logging info (may be some debug logs) as to what's going on with the time source application.

Also, after a quick search, it looks like the Kafka Producer batch's timeout exception does arise in some kubernetes environment and do you think you are running into one of those?